# Notification alert to another user after the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, notifications

I am new in php and i really need  to know how the notification can be send to the another user if the form is submitted by one user. for example .. the employee will submit the workpaln for entire 1 month and after submitted it should be notified to the department boss that the form is submitted and he/she can look at it ?

Comment: How should the department boss be notified? Mail? Website? Messenger? ...?

Answer (score 0):

When an employee submit the form at that time you can send an E-MAIL to department boss as a notification.
You can describe workpaln detail in email body.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , but the notification should be shown in the department boss page ...

Comment: This can be achieved by using NODE JS http://nodejs.org/ and SOCKET IO http://socket.io/

Comment: can you provide the example in a simple way ?